# Sitecore habitat build fails in vsts

Tags: habitat

I would like to setup CI/CD for sitecore habitat project for learning purpose. I'm able to restore the nuget package but build is not succeeding.Below is my build definition.
[image]

I have not done any changes in the sitecore habitat build. just downloaded the source from Github and trying. Build is happening properly in local visual studio without any issues but failed in the vsts.

Error as follows.

> Done Building Project
>   "D:\a\1\s\src\Feature\Language\Tests\Sitecore.Feature.Language.Tests.csproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED. Project "D:\a\1\s\Habitat.sln" (1) is
>   building
>   "D:\a\1\s\src\Feature\Maps\tests\Sitecore.Feature.Maps.Tests.csproj"
>   (35) on node 1 (default targets). PrepareForBuild:   Creating
>   directory "bin\Debug\".   Creating directory "obj\Debug\". Done
>   Building Project
>   "D:\a\1\s\src\Feature\Maps\tests\Sitecore.Feature.Maps.Tests.csproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED. Project "D:\a\1\s\Habitat.sln" (1) is
>   building
>   "D:\a\1\s\src\Feature\Media\Tests\Sitecore.Feature.Media.Tests.csproj"
>   (36) on node 1 (default targets). PrepareForBuild:   Creating
>   directory "bin\Debug\".   Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
>        Copying file from "obj\Debug\Sitecore.Foundation.Installer.Tests.dll.config" to
>   "bin\Debug\Sitecore.Foundation.Installer.Tests.dll.config".
>   CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:   Copying file from
>   "obj\Debug\Sitecore.Foundation.Installer.Tests.dll" to
>   "bin\Debug\Sitecore.Foundation.Installer.Tests.dll".
>   Sitecore.Foundation.Installer.Tests ->
>   D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\Installer\tests\bin\Debug\Sitecore.Foundation.Installer.Tests.dll
>   Copying file from "obj\Debug\Sitecore.Foundation.Installer.Tests.pdb"
>   to "bin\Debug\Sitecore.Foundation.Installer.Tests.pdb". Done Building
>   Project
>   "D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\Installer\tests\Sitecore.Foundation.Installer.Tests.csproj"
>   (default targets). Project "D:\a\1\s\Habitat.sln" (1) is building
>   "D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\LocalDatasource\tests\Sitecore.Foundation.LocalDatasource.Tests.csproj"
>   (46) on node 1 (default targets). 
>   ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs(7,18): error CS0234: The type or
>   namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are
>   you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj]
>   ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs(8,17): error CS0234: The type or
>   namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj]
>   ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs(13,20): error CS0234: The type or
>   namespace name 'Diagnostics' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Sitecore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj]
>   Infrastructure\MvcControllerServicesConfigurator.cs(3,21): error
>   CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj]
>   Infrastructure\MvcControllerServicesConfigurator.cs(4,20): error
>   CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DependencyInjection' does not
>   exist in the namespace 'Sitecore' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)
>   [D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj]
>   Infrastructure\MvcControllerServicesConfigurator.cs(6,54): error
>   CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IServicesConfigurator' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   [D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj]
>   Infrastructure\MvcControllerServicesConfigurator.cs(8,31): error
>   CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IServiceCollection' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   [D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj]
>   ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs(19,64): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name 'IServiceCollection' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   [D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\DependencyInjection\code\Sitecore.Foundation.DependencyInjection.csproj]
>
> ```
>   5 Warning(s)
> 23 Error(s) Time Elapsed 00:00:42.00 Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
> ```

Comment: Is this using the latest Habitat release? And you're sure there were no errors/warnings during the nuget restore?

Comment: I was getting some issue when i was using the latest release. yeah there is no issue with nuget restore. It's working fine. One month ago i download github habitat code and it's working fine. I'm using it for learning. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a quick VSTS build against Habitat `master` and was able to get it working, through the Build step at least. (Tests would require more work as FakeDB needs a Sitecore `license.xml`.)

[image: build configuration]

Some notes on the config:

- I used the ASP.NET build template
- Defaulted to nuget 4.4.1 for me
- Needed to configure the nuget restore to use the Habitat nuget.config
- You need to set the `BuildConfiguration` variable to `debug` because of [this](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/issues/435)

Otherwise it "just worked."

Comment: @arjunan - No problem, please accept the answer if this gave you the solution you needed.